# How to get Highlighted Text from a String in Appium

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, appium

Let says String is 'HelloWorld' and in this 'Hello' is Highlighted.How to get only highlighted text or how to validate that Hello is Highlighted .On using getText() it gives whole string Helloworld.

[Attached image for that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI91V.png)

Comment: Share what you have attempted until now so we could help

Comment: @Akshay I just need to match the case.Like what i have entered is shown highlighted or not ..

Comment: check for html tags used to Highlight the text and if exist extract it

Comment: @Pawan I am working on Mobile app and using Appium. here no html tag is available